# how to design a database table with similar entries

Tags: database, database-design

I currently have a table that has the majority (like 99%) of the data of a field dependent on a single field but the other 1% is dependent on other fields.

For example, I have the following price table

```
product PK
color PK
cost
```

The following are some entries in that table

```
product|color|cost
pen|red|$1.00
pen|blue|$1.00
pen|green|$1.00
etc....
pen|black|$0.90
pen|white|$0.85
pencil|red|$0.50
pencil|blue|$0.50
pencil|green|$0.50
etc...
pencil|black|$0.35
pencil|gray|$0.40
```

The problem I'm having with this table is that whenever I have to add a single product or color I have to add hundreds of similar entries to this table.

I'm currently thinking of storing the data in the following way

```
pen|all_other_colors|$1.00
pen|black|$0.90
pen|white|$0.85
pencil|all_other_colors|$0.50
pencil|black|$0.35
pencil|gray|$0.40
```

Am I on the right track or is there a better database design that handles this problem? Any help or links would be appreciated. I can't get the right wording to google for this problem.

Comment: could you summarize your problem? Is it that you do not want to manage each price separately, or ? Even without prices, you would need to manage which product-combinations are available

Comment: In my design, I have the assumption that a product can have any color in the colors table. I was hoping to reduce the need to insert hundreds of product-color combination entries everytime I add a new product (which occurs frequently) and deal only with the exceptions in the pricing for product-color combination (which is rare.) Your answer is kind of what I was looking for. I'm probably going with an "exception" table, though I'm not sure if that violates any database design theory. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `BaseProduct` has all product names and their prices
- `Product` has all available valid product-color combinations
- `ColorPrice` is the difference (offset) from the base price.
- `ColorCharge` has **only rows with exception pricing** (no rows for ColorPrice = 0)

[image]

To get  info for a specific base product (`specific_prodict_id`)

```
select
      b.ProductName
    , c.ColorName
    , b.ProductPrice + coalesce(x.ColorPrice, 0.0) as ProductPrice
from      Product     as p
join      BaseProduct as b on b.BaseProductID = p.BaseProductID
join      Color       as c on c.ColorId       = p.ColorId
left join ColorCharge as x on x.BaseProductID = p.BaseProductID and x.ColorID = p.ColorID
where p.BaseProductID = specific_prodict_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to normalize database tables

break it in three tables as below:

**Products**

```
id | product
```

**colors**

```
id | color
```

**product_cost**

```
id |  Product_id | color_id | Cost
```

Comment: I do have a products table and a color table but I still have the same problem. Adding an entry to the products table forces me to create hundreds of similar entries to the product_cost table.

Comment: they will not be similar use unique primary key for each product - color- cost combination

Comment: If I add a product like a marker to the products table, and for the hundreds of colors in the color table the price for the markers are the same except for the markers with the colors black and red, the correct way to do it is by adding hundreds of entries to the product_cost table?

Answer (score 0):

You could group colors together and then insert the price for the whole group:

[image]

And your example could be represented similarly to this...

```
PRICE:

    PRODUCT_ID  GROUP_ID    PRICE
    pen         1           $1.00
    pen         2           $0.90
    pen         3           $0.85    
    pencil      1           $0.50
    pencil      2           $0.35
    pencil      4           $0.40

GROUP:

    GROUP_ID
    1
    2
    3
    4

COLOR_GROUP:

    GROUP_ID    COLOR_ID
    1           red
    1           blue
    1           green
    2           black
    3           white
    4           gray

COLOR:

    COLOR_ID
    red
    blue
    green
    black
    white
    gray
```

Whether the increased complexity is worth it is up to you...